# CSS Safari / mobile - Translate and min-height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have [site](http://demo.kybernaut.cz/ommo), which is fine on Chrome, Firefox and IE but on Safari (Win version) it does weird things.

First of all min-height of image is not working, even if it should be supported and I've got some troubles with positioning to vertical center.

```
.carousel .item img {
    max-height: 50vh;
    min-height: 200px;  
    margin: auto;
}

.ommo-main {
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
}
.ommo-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%,-65%);
    -ms-transform:: translate(0%,-65%);
    -webkit: translate(0%,-65%);
    -moz-transform:: translate(0%,-65%);
    -o-transform: translate(0%,-65%);
    -webkit-transform: -webkit-translate(0%,-65%);
    transform: translateY(-65%);
}
```

All code in [bootply HERE](http://www.bootply.com/udyGw3SDQc).

And in mobile phone, one of my as easy as possible browsers (Javelin, Xiaomi Redmi 2), I've got [this issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r3vr652z4yxe03c/Screenshot_2015-11-05-17-58-49_com.nubelacorp.javelin.png?dl=0), but not sure if it's not just a cache.

Could anybody help me, please? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Safari 5...dead browser. Hardly worth supporting. Viewport units aren't supported to start by Safari 5...oh, and that's an odd way to do vertical centering.

Comment: Oh....It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with Safari on Windows, which is somehow not supporting VH and VW units, on MAC OS X it works fine.